# Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core 2.0 shared satellite assembly and in main project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently I started a ASP.NET Core 2.0 solution. I needed to separate ViewModels classes in a project to share with other projects. Every view model class has its DataAnnotations properties and I need to use globalization and localization. Every project that uses ViewModels project as reference also has its own Language resource in Resources/Controllers and Resources/Views folders.

Example of LoginViewModel.cs in Backend project:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password"))]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

According to [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization), I could create a SharedResource class and a SharedResource.es.resx (not a default resource file like SharedResource.resx) and by setting custom class DataAnnotation localizer Provider in main ASP.NET project by using following code in ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
services.AddMvc()
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
             {
                options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) => factory.Create(typeof(Backend.Resources.SharedResources));
             });
```

in Configure Method:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("es-CO")
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions()
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture("en-US"),
            SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
            SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
        });
```

I tried before mentioned scenario however when I run app, Login cshtml that uses LoginViewModel shows UserName and Password as it and not "Usuario" and "Contraseña" as they are in SharedResource.es.resx. ¿Is not possible to use or inject IStringLocalizer in an assembly so I must use the default Resource Files?

I hope being clear!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [MSDN page you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization):

> ### Resource file naming
>
> Resources are named for the full type name of their class minus the assembly name. For example, a French resource in a project whose main assembly is `LocalizationWebsite.Web.dll` for the class `LocalizationWebsite.Web.Startup` would be named `Startup.fr.resx`. A resource for the class `LocalizationWebsite.Web.Controllers.HomeController` would be named `Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx`. If your targeted class's namespace is not the same as the assembly name you will need the full type name. For example, in the sample project a resource for the type `ExtraNamespace.Tools` would be named `ExtraNamespace.Tools.fr.resx`.

Since your model class is named `Backend.LoginViewModel` and presumably the assembly name is `Backend`, the resource file should be named `LoginViewModel.resx` for the default culture and `LoginViewModel.<culture>.resx` for each localized culture.

> In the sample project, the `ConfigureServices` method sets the `ResourcesPath` to "Resources", so the project relative path for the home controller's French resource file is `Resources/Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx`. Alternatively, you can use folders to organize resource files. For the home controller, the path would be `Resources/Controllers/HomeController.fr.resx`. If you don't use the `ResourcesPath` option, the `.resx` file would go in the project base directory. The resource file for `HomeController` would be named `Controllers.HomeController.fr.resx`. The choice of using the dot or path naming convention depends on how you want to organize your resource files.

This path clearly must be within the **main AspNetCore assembly** or it won't be able to find these folders.

Comment: NightOwl888, ¿Backend.LoginViewModel.resx must reside in a specific folder into the Backend Project? ¿I can use the resource directly in this way: [Display(Name ="UserName")] or this other way: [Display(Name ="UserName", ResourceType = typeof(LoginViewModel))]?

Comment: My question is focused to try to solve the situation when ViewModels with properties and dataannotations reside in an different project than main project where cshtml that display such data annotations display names by label-for automatically shows in the correct language, ¿where do I put that resx file to resolve language for data annotations? I would like main ASP.NET core project shows for example a cshtml view that uses LoginViewModel (in backend project), the labels text be shown in the correct language based on for example: Display(Name="UserName").

Comment: I tried as MSDN examples but it doesn't work. Examples are focused View Models resides in Main ASP.NET project, into Models folder.